# printing an order without invoicing in magento

Tags: magento-1.7

Is there a way to print an order in Magento that has not been invoiced yet? My client needs to be able to print things as soon as they come in, without having to invoice them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks everyone for all their suggestions. What ended up working for me was the [Fooman Email Attachment extension](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/fooman-email-attachments.html) It was free and allowed me to print the orders before they were processed which is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 2):

I use the PrintPDF extension from SNM-Portal (http://www.snm-portal.com/pdf-print.html) for this, it allows you to design the layout for all the PDF types (order/offer, invoice, shipment, creditmemo) and print them thru the backend. The PDF for the order/offer is based on the order details so there is no invoice needed to create this file.

For the automatic printing of the orders (we use it as a packagelist) I build my own extension  that creates a PDF and prints it on a local printer in the warehouse.

Comment: Would this allow me to print before I create an invoice?

Comment: Yes, the PDF Offer like they call it adds a button on the order detail page in the backend, here you can get the PDF and print it. There is no need to have the order invoiced to print it.

Comment: thanks! So it's http://www.snm-portal.com/pdf-print.html? Do you happen to know of anyone that wouldn't be so pricy since I really don't need all the other bells and whistles?

Comment: thanks! So it's snm-portal.com/pdf-print.html? Do you happen to know of anyone that wouldn't be so pricy since I really don't need all the other bells and whistles?

Comment: I've used SNM-PORTAL however it was causing my transactional emails not to send automatically and my contact form to stop working... any other suggestions? @VladimirKerkhoff

Answer (score 1):

**Without** the code too much, I think you have the following options:

1. You can create a shipping
2. just BCC it to your client (when the order confirmation mail is send)

And **with** changing the code:

1. you can add a second order email via observer and send it
2. you can copy the shipping creation or invoice creation code, add a button "Print" and then create a PDF

If you ask me BCCing the order email might be the best option, because it is push (the client doesn't need to check for new orders) and can just print from his outlook, thunderbird, whatever...)

Comment: would this mean I would still need to "create shipping" for the order?

Comment: Would WHAT mean to create a shipping? 1.1 Yes the others no.